# Queuing theory: m/m/s queue with multi-size customers

Tags: analysis, statistics, queueing-theory

I'm doing a personal project where i need to estimate the average waiting time for each customer in a queue system with s servers. In my case though, a customer can spawn its service on more than one server: imagine a parallel computing system which schedules multiprocess jobs: each job can spawn k<= s processes

So i am asking myself:

1. is it right to see any n-size customer as n single customers in the estimate of statistics? I.e. if there are jobs with 5 processes served per second i'd have a.service rate of 5 jobs per second, not just one
2. if the (1) was right, it keeps to be right despite any change in the scheduling policy?
3. could the size of a customer that enters the queue affect its waiting time?

I don t know where to find this information because seems that there are not so much studies upon my problem, so i want to ask if i'm wrong. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at [this lecture slides](http://www.csus.edu/indiv/b/blakeh/mgmt/documents/opm101supplc.pdf) as a start.
There is an example of MULTISERVER WAITING LINE MODEL on page 11, that should be helpful.